# Magento 2 Rest API youtube video missing values

Tags: python, api, magento, youtube, magento2

I have simple question regarding the Magento V1 media API. I'm trying to add a video to a product but it keeps telling me that is missing values.

I'm trying to add the data from Odoo (python) like this:

```
    videoFile = {
        "entry": {
            'position': position,
            'media_type': 'external-video',
            'disabled': False,
            'label': 'Holassss',
            'types': ['image', 'small-image', 'thumbnail'],
            'content': {
                'base64_encoded_data': base64.b64encode(urllib.request.urlopen("https://img.youtube.com/vi/axwE9q7llEQ/0.jpg").read()).decode('ascii'),
                'type': 'image/jpeg',
                'name': '0.jpg'
            },
            'extension_attributes': {
                'video_content': {
                    'media_type': 'external-video',
                    'video_provider': 'youtube',
                    'video_url': 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=axwE9q7llEQ',
                    'video_title': 'Titulo',
                    'video_description': 'Description',
                    'video_metadata': None,
                }
            }
        }
    }
    cc = json.dumps(videoFile)
    productUrl = url + "/index.php/rest/V1/products/" + productSku + "/media"
```

Eventually I'll add the content using the https://www.youtube.com/oembed?url=youtubeurl&format=json response.

I'm following the API documentation (http://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index_20.html) for 
catalogProductAttributeMediaGalleryManagementV1 (/V1/products/{sku}/media)

**Error:**
"message": "Option values that are not specified."

Please advice me on which values I'm missing and which I can leave NULL. Also let me know if there is a way to let Magento automatically get the description and other data (as on the admin panel) instead of providing it myself. last but not least, I think this documentation is missing some data. This already happened to me before with a different call and a couple of "optional" values were actually required. Is there another documentation web page?

Thank you very much.